# phpExcel insertNewRowBefore does not correctly update the Cell IDs in the formulas

Tags: php, phpexcel

Also filed an issue on https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/275

Repro:

1) Fill, for instance, cells A1,B2,C1,C2,C4 with arbitrary values

2) Set C3=A1*B2*C1*C2*C4

3) Call insertNewRowBefore(1,1) and observe that the formula is corrupted: =A2*B3*C3*C3*C5 instead of A2*B3*C3*C4*C5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe fixed in the latest [develop](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) branch on github

Comment: I am using 1.8.0 and I am using  removeRow; but using removeRow not updating the reference formulas.

Comment: @SazzadHossainKhan - in that case, please provide a working example to demonstrate this problem, and raise it as an issue on the codeplex issue log... as far as my own tests go, it works; clearly you've found a circumstance in which it fails, but unless I'm made aware of that circumstance then I can't do anything to fix it

Comment: I have reported one issue phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/20962 Can you please take a look there?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the latest [develop branch from github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel): this is a [known issue](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/20397) that has been reported already and should be fixed

Comment: Unfortunately this is quite something else. I'll open an issue in PHPExcel. See also https://github.com/GerHobbelt/PHPExcel/commit/7d6f6e038db6252a1056cf31525852db822a066e

Comment: I have added a reference to an example which reproduces the problem with the very latest develop HEAD revision: see my comment in the relevant issue: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/275

Comment: OK, I'll take a look at it this weekend